# How to transform skew-symmetric matrix into vector

Tags: linear-algebra

We can build a skew-symmetric matrix from a vector $v$ using formula
$$S(v) = \begin{pmatrix} v \times i \ \ v \times j \ \ v \times k \end{pmatrix}$$   where $i,j,k$ are  vectors of the standard basis.

But how to obtain vector $v$  from its skew-symetric matrix?

Is there any linear formula for that ?

**AFTER 2 hours**

I think I have found solution:

$$v=-ij^TS(v)k-jk^TS(v)i-ki^TS(v)j$$

Thank you for discussion.

**AFTER 20 hours**

I have one **additional question:**

could $v$ be calculated with one formula also from $S^2(v)$ ?

**AFTER 31 hours**

It seems  it's hard to obtain straightforward formula.

$v$ can be obtained from $S^2(v)=vv^T-v^TvI$ but by a rather tedious analysis.

Comment: Only for understanding: Is the standard basis $i=(1,0,0)$, $j=(0,1,0)$ and $k=(0,0,1)$?

Comment: Yes. We should use vectors of the standard basis.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258775/from-a-vector-to-a-skew-symmetric-matrix?rq=1  and that already has a good answer.

Comment: Colin, I don't see a duplicate. Just give me a formula ( if it exists)..

Comment: Note that, in general, left-multiplying a matrix by the $i$th row of the identity will pick out its $i$th row. Similarly, right-multiplying by the $j$th column of the identity will pick out its $j$th column. This is basically what you’re doing in the solution that you found.

Comment: Basically or not basically it was just needed to obtain solution. BTW you haven't noticed missing minus which I'm inserting now.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $Sv=0$. 

In other words $v$ resides in the nullspace of $S\,-$ in fact it's the only vector in the space.

With this insight, we can write a formula in terms of the pseudoinverse and an arbitrary vector
$$\eqalign{
 b &= (I-S^+S)\,a \cr
 v &= b \,\frac{\|v\|}{\|b\|}\cr
}$$
There is an explicit formula for the pseudoinverse of a $3\times 3$ skew-symmetric matrix 
$$\eqalign{
 S^+ &= \frac{-2S}{\|S\|_F^2}\cr
}$$
Also, the length of $v$ is related to the norm of $S$ 
$$\eqalign{
 \|S\|_F^2 &= 2\,\|v\|^2 \implies
 \|v\| &= \frac{\,\|S\|_F}{{\sqrt 2}} \cr
}$$
Assembling all these pieces yields
$$\eqalign{
 b &= \|S\|_F^2\,a + 2S^2a \cr
 v &= \pm\,b\,\,\frac{\|S\|_F}{{\sqrt 2}\,\,\|b\|_F} \cr
}$$

Comment: very interesting ... but what does index $F$ mean?  What from do you take the formula for explicit formula of the pseudoinverse?

Comment: I have found that $F$ stands for Frobenius norm,  here is I suppose $\sqrt {2(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$ taking into account 3 independent entries of $S$, but still I'm not convinced for the pseudoinverse formula..

Comment: Greg, I've tested your method..
The method is interesting (I upvoted it), however it has some limitations.  
It strongly depends on the choice of the vector $a$ - it can not  be selected randomly because it could happen that $   \|S\|_F^2\,a + 2S^2a =0$.    
See the following example:

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0.6 & 0 \\ -0.6 & 0 & 0.8 \\ 0 & -0.8 & 0  \end{bmatrix}^2\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0   \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 0   \end{bmatrix}$ and $ \|S\|_F^2=2$. 
In fact it can happen always when $a$ lies in the span of $S$, what is hard to guess in general case.  
So it seems that the method can be used taking into account this restriction.

Comment: @Widawensen, that is an interesting counterexample. I suppose the method should be modified so that the vector $a$ is chosen subject to the constraint that $b\ne 0$. Otherwise you have the term $\frac{b}{\|b\|_F}$, which is indeterminate.

Comment: Yes, so we can't take a vector $a$ which is orthogonal to the $v$.

Comment: But since we don't know $v$ ahead of time, the only way to determine if $a$ is orthogonal is to run it through @greg 's formula. If $b$ turns out to be zero, then pick another $a$ and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v=(x,y,z)^\top$

Then

$v\times i = (0, z,-y)^\top$

$v\times j = (-z, 0,x)^\top$

$v\times k = (y, -x,0)^\top$

This means that $S(v) = \begin{pmatrix}0&-z&y\\z&0&-x\\-y&x&0\end{pmatrix}$

Now you can easily see the components of $v$

Comment: Yes, I know that but the problem is inverse. How to obtain  whole vector $v$ in a single formula from $S(v)$ not by taking entries of the matrix.

Comment: $B$ can not be a matrix because of the dimensions.