# Square root of matrix that is a square of skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's suppose we have a matrix $A$ (dimension $3\times 3$) which is the square of some skew-symmetric matrix $S$ i.e. $A=S^2$.
How to obtain from $A$  its **skew-symmetric** square root $S$?

Comment: This question is related to my previous one [StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1759976/how-to-transform-skew-symmetric-matrix-into-vector)

Comment: Um, $A=S^2$, so you have it already. Or are you looking for the skew-symmetric matrix $S$, given $A$?

Comment: I'm looking for $S$ (assuming $S$ is skew-symmetric), given $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, every eigenvalue of the skew-symmatrix $S$ will be purely imaginary. In this specific case where $S$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix, we will have the 3 distinct eigenvalues $i\lambda, -i\lambda, 0$, where $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.

According to this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Spectral_theory), our real skew-symmetric matrix $S$ can be written in the form
$$S = Q\cdot \Sigma\cdot  Q^\top,$$
where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\Sigma$ is of the form $$ \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &-\lambda &0\\
\lambda & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

---

Matrix $A$ will have the real, non - positive eigenvalues $-\lambda^2, -\lambda^2, 0$. Moreover, since $A$ is symmetric it can be written as:
$$A = V \cdot \begin{bmatrix} -\lambda^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -\lambda^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\cdot V^\top,$$
where $V$ is some orthogonal matrix. So, to answer your question, since you are given the matrix $A$, write it down in the previous form and in order to find $S$, set $Q = V$ and $\Sigma$ as written above.

Notice that alternating the signs in matrix $\Sigma$, you will get either the matrix $S$ or $-S$.

Comment: Great answer, but .. how to find $V$? $S^2$  I suppose is of rank 2.

Comment: Ok. So 3 eigenvectors, but one eigenvalue is 0. What to do with that?

Comment: $V$ has as its columns $3$ orthogonal vectors. Since you have $V$, you already have $Q$. Since you know the eigenvalues of $A$, you can construct the matrix $\Sigma$ as well.  Then finding $S$ is a matter of matrix multiplication, i.e. $S= Q \cdot \Sigma \cdot Q^T.$

Comment: Eigenvector from 0 eigenvalue will be unigue? $Av_0=0$. I quess it would be perpendicular to the plane defined by $A$.

Comment: Yes, it will be unique (up to a scalar).

Comment: And scale doesn't matter?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. If $\vec u$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the zero eigenvalue, then $c \cdot\vec u, c\in\mathbb R^*$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the same eigenvalue. Now, if the vectors $\vec v,\vec u$ are orthogonal, i.e. their inner product equals to zero, then the vectors $c\vec u, \vec v$ are orthogonal, as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patient explanations. So we obtained from this procedure unigue solution skew-symmetric $S$ matrix (up the the sign).

Comment: As I stated, from $A$ satisfying the conditions above, we can retrieve 2 skew - symmetric matrices! Either $S$ or $-S$. You are welcome!